# How to install GLSL shader mod on Minecraft 1.5.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I tried installing the [GLSL Shaders Mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1803624-152-glsl-shaders-for-minecraft-152/), but no matter what I try, it just uses the default lighting. I'm using Minecraft 1.5.2 with Magic Launcher 1.1.4 and I have these mods installed (in order):

1. minecraftforge-universal-1.5.2-7.8.0.684
2. OptiFine_1.5.2_HD_U_D3
3. ShadersMod-mc1.5.2-ofud3-1.46
4. [1.5.2]ReiMinimap_v3.3_05
5. JourneyMap2.6.0_MC1.5.2

I have installed shaders, none of them work.

Comment: This is an awfully useful question, I've struggled with GLSL to no end. A shame the question will soon be obsolete with Resourse Packs and stuff, but I'd still deem it valuable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Shaders Mod just adds code to *use* shaders – it doesn't bundle any actual shader files you can use. You have to download a shader pack now, and there are lots of different ones for different effects and tastes.

For example, [here are my shader packs](http://www.mediafire.com/download/pajcc1btg6kl2bz/shaderpacks.rar).

To install shaders:

1. Drop them into the `shaderpack` folder located under `.minecraft`
2. Start Minecraft
3. Go to Options, click Shaders, and select the pack that suits you

Comment: I guess the shaders I found didn't work. Thanks for sharing all of those shaders.

Comment: What do you drop in the `.minecraft\shaderpack` folder? The zip file itself? I extracted the 21 zip files from that linked **rar**, and placed them into the `.minecraft\shaderpack` folder. No [**Shaders** button](http://i.imgur.com/zbNUPV0.png) appears under **Options**. [Some people say the folder should be called `shaderpacks` (plural)](http://blog.16tonweight.com/2014/01/19/installing-seus-shaders-mod-in-minecraft-1-7-2/). But putting the zips in a `shaderpacks` folder doesn't work either. The rar contains a `shaderpacks` folder. Should it be `.minecraft\shaderpack\shaderpacks\*.zip` ?